# How to batch rename multiple files in 2 folders with different extensions

Tags: powershell

I have the following case:

- I have two folders with multiple files having matching names and different extensions for example:

  ```
    \source\A\345.jpg
    \source\B\345.dat
  ```

I want to do two operations:

1. select a set of random files from both folders and copy to another folder. The below code only works for 1 set and my current obstacle is using the same random number for both folders/extension types so I can end up with a matching set of `.jpg` and `.dat` files.
2. Rename the selected files to a random number in the range of number of unique files (`selectcount` in the below code, so the name will be a range from 1-20). But I want to rename both extensions each to a matching name. So I'll end up with:

   ```
     345.jpg ->5.jpg
     345.dat ->5.dat
   ```

Code:

```
$SelectCount = 20

$SourcePath1  = "C:\ProjectA\source\A\*.jpg"
$SourcePath2  = "C:\ProjectA\source\B\*.dat"

$DestPath    = 'C:\ProjectA\Renamed'

If (!(test-path $DestPath)) {md $DestPath | out-null} 

$files1 = Get-ChildItem -path $SourcePath -file -recurse | Get-Random -count $SelectCount
$files2 = Get-ChildItem -path $SourcePath -file -recurse | Get-Random -count $SelectCount

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $files1.count; $i += 2) {
   copy-item $files1[$i] -destination ('{0}' -f $DestPath, ($i/2+100))
   copy-item $files1[$i+1] -destination ('{0}' -f $DestPath, ($i/2+100))
   copy-item $files2[$i] -destination ('{0}' -f $DestPath, ($i/2+100))
   copy-item $files2[$i+1] -destination ('{0}' -f $DestPath, ($i/2+100))
}
```

Comment: So where are you stuck?

Comment: For #1, I cannot assign the same random value to files of both extension, I can choose either jpg or dat, as such I will end up with only 1 set of files and I have to find a way to select the equivalent of the 2nd extension and copy it to the destination folder. For #2 I do not know how to start tbh.

Comment: @AhmedMarei I think you need to you add some conditional `If()` logic to check if the file `$_.basename` exist in `$SourcePath2` per it's recursive search and then to only do the copy item of it over to the destination and use the same math operation to save accordingly so both in the loop take the same number. There may be files in A that are not in B so you might then do the copies with rename to B after all the A item copies with conditional and checking B for matching basename finish. Get creative but you should be able to work if out.

Comment: @AhmedMarei So when you generate the random number for files in A, save it as a variable perhaps and then append that variable to the destination of files from A and then IF the conditional logic find a matching basename not counting extensions in B to then do that correlated copy operation with the rename using the random number variable. Not sure how you are generating the random number but A & B may have a different count so pick one to use as the authority for this number. Might have to use some logic if basname.ext exist in destination from B, to not do nothing, check next file type thing

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to pick files randomly from two different folders and want to make sure you have the same number of matching files based on their BaseName (the .Name property without the extension), I would do:

```
$SelectCount  = 20

$SourcePath1  = "C:\ProjectA\source\A"
$SourcePath2  = "C:\ProjectA\source\B"
$DestPath     = 'C:\ProjectA\Renamed'

# creates a new folder only if this did not already exist
$null = New-Item -Path $DestPath -ItemType Directory -Force

do {
    # get $SelectCount jpg files (in a loop to make sure you end up with 20 unique files)
    do {
        $jpgFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath1 -Filter '*.jpg' -File -Recurse | 
                    Get-Random -Count $SelectCount | Sort-Object BaseName -Unique
    } until ($jpgFiles.Count -eq $SelectCount)

    # try to find as many .dat files with similar basenames
    $datFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath2 -Filter '*.dat' -File -Recurse |
                Where-Object { $jpgFiles.BaseName -contains $_.BaseName } | Sort-Object BaseName -Unique
} until ($datFiles.Count -eq $SelectCount)

# if you want to go really, REALLY random, shuffle the $jpgFiles array here
# $jpgFiles = $jpgFiles | Sort-Object { Get-Random }

# copy and rename the matching items
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $SelectCount; $i++) {
    # copy the jpg with new name to the destination
    $jpgFiles[$i] | Copy-Item -Destination (Join-Path -Path $DestPath -ChildPath "$($i + 1).jpg")
    # find the matching .dat file and copy that too, using the same BaseName
    $datFiles | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -eq $jpgFiles[$i].BaseName } | 
                Copy-Item -Destination (Join-Path -Path $DestPath -ChildPath "$($i + 1).dat")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand how you want to rename your files - but I assumed you want to give them names that range from 1 to the specified `$SelectCount`

You basically can get all files in one `Get-ChildItem` and simply put them into pairs with `Group-Object` by checking their basename property.

In the `for` block you can do the renaming.

```
$SourcePathJpg  = "C:\ProjectA\source\A"
$SourcePathDat  = "C:\ProjectA\source\B"
$DestPath       = "C:\ProjectA\Renamed"
$SelectCount    = 20

New-Item $DestPath -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue > $null

# Get Items of both folders, group them via basename property, and get randoms
$RandomItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePathJpg, $SourcePathDat -Recurse | 
               Where-Object { $_.Extension -in '.dat','.jpg' } | 
               Group-Object BaseName | Where-Object Count -eq 2 |
               Get-Random -Count $SelectCount

# Rename the stuff, remove -PassThru if you don't want a return
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $SelectCount; $i++) {
    $RandomItems[$i].Group | Copy-Item -Destination { 
        Join-Path $DestPath ([string]($i + 1) + $_.Extension) 
    } -PassThru
}
```

Output (Remove the `-PassThru` if you don't want output):

```
    Verzeichnis: C:\ProjectA\Renamed


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 1.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 1.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 2.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 2.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 3.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 3.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 4.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 4.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 5.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 5.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 6.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 6.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 7.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 7.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 8.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 8.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 9.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 9.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 10.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 10.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 11.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 11.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 12.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 12.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 13.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 13.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 14.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 14.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 15.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 15.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 16.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 16.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 17.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 17.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 18.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 18.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 19.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 19.dat
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 20.jpg
-a----       01.02.2022     09:44              0 20.dat
```